# How to add individual hlines for each bar in a plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given a data frame and a plot as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(grp = c("a", "b", "c"),
           val = c(30, 20, 10),
           avg = c(25, 15, 5)) 

dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = grp, y = val)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

How do I amend the code above to place a unique horizontal reference line (avg) on each bar as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved via `geom_segment` like so, where I first conver `grp` to a numeric and corresponding to the default width of a bar of .9 put the `x` at .45 to the left and `xend` at .45 to the right:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(grp = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  val = c(30, 20, 10),
                  avg = c(25, 15, 5)) 

ggplot(dat, aes(x = grp, y = val)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_segment(aes(y = avg, yend = avg, 
                   x = as.numeric(factor(grp)) - .45, 
                   xend = as.numeric(factor(grp)) + .45), color = "red")
```

**EDIT** Thanks to comment by @tjebo: As hard-coding is rarely a good idea one could set the width via a variable:

```
w <- .9
...
geom_segment(aes(y = avg, yend = avg, 
                       x = as.numeric(factor(grp)) - w/2, 
                       xend = as.numeric(factor(grp)) + w/2), color = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Haha. Always the same guys with same ideas. (;

Comment: for full control over the width, I'd probably add a variable "w" or so, something akin to `w <- 0.9` and then `geom_col(width = w)` and `geom_segment(...as.numeric(x)- w/2,...`

Comment: Yep. You are absolutely right. Hard coding is rarely a good idea. I will add this as an edit. Thx.